# Trying to Clear the Blank Page That Precedes the Endnotes

Tags: macros, pdftex, endnotes, clearpage

I have been trying to eliminate the blank page which always comes before the Endnotes.

For example, in the following code, I use

```
\begin{document}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

but to no avail---

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering everyv%new chapter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\enoteheading{% changes being made here
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother %changes the catcode of @ back to 12

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand {\chapter}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexchapter*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\latexchapter{#3}}
     {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\LARGE


\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
This is Chapter I. Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}


\chapter*{} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Endnotes.}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes} % Renames `Notes' to `Endnotes'
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

followed by a blank page

[image]

followed by the Endnotes:

[image]

QUESTION: Can someone tell me how I may eliminate the unwanted blank page in the MWE?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say `\chapter*{}`? Remove it.

Comment: `\begin{document}\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}` would just force the initial page of the document to be on an odd page, but it is page 1 already.

Comment: @schtandard Thanks. That works.

Comment: By the way, this is a typical case where creating an MWE would have inevitably lead you to discover the culprit. Always try to make your examples minimal before asking a question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is unrelated to `endnotes` and unlikely to help anyone else.